# cometchat sdk joinChatroom as guest return exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, chatroom, cometchat

I'm using cometchat sdk for ios project on objective c

I log as a guest : guestLoginWithURL, after that i join group like that :

```
    [cometChatRoom joinChatroom:chatRoomName chatroomID:chatroomID chatroomPassword:@"" success:^(NSDictionary *response) {
```

there is a crash from api :

[10374:1738831] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'

When user is not a guest join Chatrooms work

Can anyone help please ?

Answer (score 0):

You're using our older SDK which we no longer support. Please move to the latest SDK in order to get this working.

Comment: I can't update to the new version sdk,  can you please provide another solution?